# How to expose two different Swagger UI pages on the same port using Springfox?

Tags: swagger-ui, springfox

I can access my Swagger UI at http://localhost:8000/swagger-ui/index.html.
I want to have something in between these URLs, such as:

http://localhost:8000/swagger-ui/animal/index.html

http://localhost:8000/swagger-ui/bird/index.html

to access it differently.

Moreover I have REST APIs in the Swagger UI. Assuming :

/animal.. - URLs starting with these should use the link that has animal URL.

/bird.. - URLs starting with these should use the link that has bird URL.

For now all of these are in one UI, and comes from the same controller.
Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Do you host Swagger UI assets directly, or is it provided by your server library/framework, e.g. Springfox, Swashbuckle, ...?

Comment: its provided by springfox

Comment: I think it's not possible. However, you can have a spec for each one...